# Incorrect syntax near TableName after running SQL query from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update some values in different tables using the said query. the query is working fine in SQL Server but when I write it in C# code, I got the following error. Can anyone help me to sort this out?

Thanks!

```cs
objc = new SqlConnection(c);
string query;
int feetP = Convert.ToInt32(tb_nFeet.Text);

query = "UPDATE tbl_ContainerP SET SaleAmount = tbl_ContainerP.SaleAmount - tbl_Bill.CurrentAmount FROM tbl_bill, tbl_ContainerP WHERE tbl_Bill.ContainerID = tbl_ContainerP.ContainerID AND tbl_Bill.InvoiceID = '" + tb_invoiceNo.Text + "'";

query += "UPDATE tbl_ContainerP SET Profit = SaleAmount - TotalAmount";

query += "UPDATE tbl_CustomerAccounts SET Balance = tbl_CustomerAccounts.Balance - tbl_Bill.CurrentAmount FROM tbl_bill, tbl_CustomerAccounts WHERE tbl_Bill.CustomerName = tbl_CustomerAccounts.CustomerName AND tbl_Bill.InvoiceID = '" + tb_invoiceNo.Text + "'";

query += "UPDATE tbl_Bill SET BuffaloFeetP = '" + feetP + "' WHERE InvoiceID='" + tb_invoiceNo.Text + "'";

query += "UPDATE tbl_Bill SET BuffaloT = BuffaloFeetQ * BuffaloFeetP";

query += "UPDATE tbl_Bill SET CurrentAmount = BuffaloT + BrainT + LiverT";

query += "UPDATE tbl_Bill SET TotalAmount = PreviousAmount + CurrentAmount";

query += "UPDATE tbl_Bill SET Balance = TotalAmount - Received";

query += "UPDATE tbl_ContainerP SET SaleAmount = tbl_ContainerP.SaleAmount + tbl_Bill.CurrentAmount FROM tbl_bill, tbl_ContainerP WHERE tbl_Bill.ContainerID = tbl_ContainerP.ContainerID AND tbl_Bill.InvoiceID = '" + tb_invoiceNo.Text + "'";

query += "UPDATE tbl_ContainerP SET Profit = SaleAmount - TotalAmount";

query += "UPDATE tbl_CustomerAccounts SET Balance= tbl_CustomerAccounts.Balance + tbl_Bill.CurrentAmount FROM tbl_bill, tbl_CustomerAccounts WHERE tbl_Bill.CustomerName = tbl_CustomerAccounts.CustomerName AND tbl_Bill.InvoiceID = '" + tb_invoiceNo.Text + "'";

objcmd = new SqlCommand(query, objc);
objc.Open();
objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
objc.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated");
```

Getting errors:

> incorrect syntax near 'tbl_CustomerAccounts'
>   incorrect syntax near 'tbl_Bill'
>   incorrect syntax near 'tbl_CustomerAccounts'

Comment: Try to output the query in a console/file. Queries such as `update tbl_Bill SET BuffaloT = BuffaloFeetQ * BuffaloFeetPupdate tbl_Bill SET CurrentAmount = BuffaloT + BrainT + LiverT` are invalid. I hope you can findtheerrorbyyourself. :)

Comment: It is not good practice to construct SQL queries by string concatenation, as it can result in SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: I would a stored procedure with all these statements!@

Comment: I would debug in SQL Server Management Studio where the error messages are much better.

Comment: To emphase what steve163351 says, munging query strnigs with constant values can introduce hard-to-debug errors.  Learn to use parameters!

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by others: this is not the way to write good and/or safe code!!! There are so many things here: SQL Injection, parameterized queries, stored procedures even DB triggers would make sense here.

For the problem itself: add semicolons at the end of each SQL statement. And use at least `StringBuilder` with the `AppendLine` function.

You should be able to find the problem right away when running in debug mode and looking at the contents of the `query` string - just copy and try to execute the code in SQl server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I resolved the issue by adding space before query start.

But late I changed the method as you guys told that it's not good practice then I uses the SQL transaction. Now my code is working fine